# Template Admin Materialize

Tags: angular

A empresa comprou um template para implementarmos um menu, mas ao clicar no botão do menu está dando este erro no console:

> ```
> FullComponent.html:34 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined
>     at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (FullComponent.html:34)
>     at handleEvent (core.js:13547)
>     at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15056)
>     at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:14643)
>     at dispatchEvent (core.js:9962)
>     at eval (core.js:10587)
>     at HTMLButtonElement.eval (platform-browser.js:2628)
>     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
>     at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4740)
>     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
> ```

A linha 34 do arquivo **FullComponent.html** está assim:

```xml
<button mat-icon-button (click)="snav.toggle()" value="sidebarclosed">
   <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Entendo que fiz o que está no arquivo original, mas está faltando algo que não sei, pois quando rodo o template que compramos funciona normalmente.

O template que compramos é este: https://wrappixel.com/demos/angular-admin-templates/material-angular/material

---

Quando pesquiso no que compramos, vem somente um, conforme imagem em anexo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**TypeScript**

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import { MediaMatcher } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, NgZone, OnDestroy, ViewChild, HostListener, Directive, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuItems } from '../../shared/menu-items/menu-items';
import { AppHeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { AppSidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';

import { PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar'; 
/** @title Responsive sidenav */
@Component({
  selector: 'app-full-layout',
  templateUrl: 'full.component.html',
  styleUrls: [],
}) 
export class FullComponent implements OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
  mobileQuery: MediaQueryList;
  dir = 'ltr';
  green: boolean;
  blue: boolean = true;
  dark: boolean;
  minisidebar: boolean;
  boxed: boolean;
  danger: boolean;
  showHide:boolean;
  sidebarOpened;    

  public config: PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface = {};
  private _mobileQueryListener: () => void;

  constructor(changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, media: MediaMatcher, public menuItems: MenuItems) {
    this.mobileQuery = media.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)');
    this._mobileQueryListener = () => changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    this.mobileQuery.addListener(this._mobileQueryListener);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.mobileQuery.removeListener(this._mobileQueryListener);
  }
 ngAfterViewInit() {
     //This is for the topbar search
     (<any>$(".srh-btn, .cl-srh-btn")).on('click', function () {
            (<any>$(".app-search")).toggle(200);
        });
     //This is for the megamenu

  }

  // Mini sidebar


}
```

Comment: Tem como vc postar o código do componente(ts)? Aparentemente snav e undefined. Como vc esta definindo esta variável?

Comment: Pesquisei por **snav.toggle()**, mas só apreceu no HTML que está dando o erro. Inseri a imagem

Comment: posta o typescript desse componente

Comment: Incluído na primeira página

Comment: Bom a propriedade snav não existe no componente. Logicamente sera undefined.

Comment: Sim, eu percebi isto, mas está assim no original, por isto perguntei.